# Verbos que mudam de sentido ao serem usados na conjugação reflexiva

Tags: verbos

Estes tempos estive pensando sobre o verbo *[mudar](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mudar)*. Em seu uso mais comum significa *substituir*, *trocar* ou *alterar*. No entanto aos ser usado na conjugação reflexiva (eu *me* mudei) seu sentido (pelo menos em PT-BR) é o de mudar de habitação ou residência.

Achei este fato curioso e gostaria de saber de outros verbos que possuem o mesmo comportamento, no entanto não sei se há um nome para este fenômeno. O que me ocorreu primeiro foi buscar por [verbos *pronominais* ou *reflexivos*](http://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/diferencas-entre-os-verbos-reflexivos-pronominais.htm), mas assim eu estaria buscando apenas verbos que exigem ou podem ser acompanhados por pronomes pessoais oblíquos.

- Existe um termo para classificar estes verbos que mudam de sentido ao serem acompanhados por um pronome pessoal oblíquo?
- Como posso achar outros verbos deste tipo?

Comment: Interessante pergunta. Em pt_PT mudar-se também toma o mesmo significado. Não sei porquê o primeiro exemplo de que me lembrei foi *largar* - que normalmente significa *deixar, ceder, libertar, soltar*, no entanto, mas *largar-se* ou *abrir-se* pode informalmente ou em calão significar *[peidar](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/peidar), bufar ou traquejar* hahah

Comment: No teu exemplo, o significado muda apenas na conjugação reflexa, não simplesmente por juntares um pronome pessoal oblíquo. Em qualquer verbo transitivo direto, o objeto direto pode em princípio ser substituído por pronome pessoal oblíquo sem alterar o significado: «se ainda não **mudaste** o óleo ao carro,  temos de **o mudar**». Portanto referes-te a pronomes pessoais oblíquos em geral, ou apenas a conjugação reflexa?

Comment: @Jacinto, realmente me refiro ao seu uso na conjugação reflexa. Inclusive a 1a versão do titulo da questão era "verbos que mudam de sentido ao serem usados reflexivamente", mas achei que não ficou claro. Vou editar a questão e corrigi-la.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chamam-se `verbos frasais` aqueles que mudam de significado quando acompanhados de pronomes pessoais oblíquos, preposições e palavras de outras classes gramaticais. Da [Wikipedia](https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb):

> O fenômeno dos "phrasal verbs" também ocorre na língua portuguesa. Contudo, não é muito comum. É mais encontrado no português coloquial falado no Brasil . Exemplos: "Não quero mais saber de você! Cai fora!" (cair fora = sair, retirar-se); "Depois de ter sido xingada, ela partiu para cima dele com uma faca." (partir para cima = atacar algo ou alguém).

#### Exemplos com pronomes pessoais oblíquos

> - **[Tocar](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Tocar)**: Pôr a mão ou o dedo em. *(ex. Eu toquei o vaso)*
> - **Tocar-se**: perceber, dar por si. *(ex. Entrei em casa e nem me toquei que você estava no sofá)*
>
> ---
>
> - **[Deitar](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Deitar)**: Estender ao comprido.
> - **Deitar-se**: Estender-se para dormir.
> - **Deitar-se com**: Fazer sexo com alguém. *(ex. [Berto obriga Lindinalva a se deitar com ele](http://globoplay.globo.com/v/2049540/))*
>
> ---
>
> - **Conter**: Ser constituído de algo.  *(ex. Este alimento contém glúten.)*
> - **Conter-se**: Impedir que alguém aja. *(ex. Quando a vi, não me contive e a abracei.)*

#### Outros exemplos

Além destes exemplos, acredito que o mais notório seja o verbo `dar`. Segundo o dicionário [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/da) (ênfase minha):

> - **sem preposição**: Ceder gratuitamente (ex.: dar um cigarro).
> - **Dar + per**: Tomar conhecimento na altura em que acontece (ex.: a vítima nem deu pelo furto).
> - **Dar + com**: Achar, descobrir, encontrar (ex.: deu com a fotografia escondida no livro).
> - **Dar + para**: Conseguir ou ser possível (ex.: sei que prometemos, mas não deu para ir). [Verbo impessoal]

---

*Editado conforme comentários*

Comment: A pergunta trata-se só da diferença entre duas formas específicas de um verbo: a forma pronominal e a forma não pronominal. Por exemplo, *ir* (eu vou) e *ir-se* (eu vou-me) tem significados bastante diferentes, mas não há nenhuma ideia de reflexividade (*ir* não é transitivo, pelo que não teria sentido)

Comment: Sim. Mas a pergunta é: "existe um termo para verbos que mudam de significado ao serem acompanhados de um pronome pessoal oblíquo?" A resposta é: sim, chamam-se verbos frasais, que mudam de significado não só com pronomes pessoais oblíquos mas também com palavras de outras classes gramaticais.

Comment: @BellAppLab sendo «chamam-se verbos frasais» a resposta que queres dar, acho que a tua resposta ficaria muito mais sólida com um par de exemplos de «verbos frasais» com pronomes oblíquos :) , em vez de um exemplo sem pronomes oblíquos.

Comment: Editado confirme sugestões.

Comment: Nalguns dos teus exemplos o clítico pode ser substituído por um nome sem alterar o significado do verbo: *eu deitei-me (para dormir)/eu deitei o bebé*; *não me contive/não contive o Pedro, e ele começou a disparatar em frente de toda a gente*. Portanto o clítico não altera o significado nestes casos.

Comment: @Jacinto Precisamente. Acho que justamente por isso não se fala a respeito dos verbos frasais no português. Eles são mais plásticos, ao que me parece. Com exceção, na minha opinião, do caso "dar+para", em que não há essa superposição de sentidos mediante o acréscimo da preposição.

Comment: Não creio que verbos frasais sejam relevantes nesta pergunta. A questão não é verbos que mudam de sentido ao mudar a preposição. Pede-se é verbos que com clítico ´reflexo' significam uma coisa, e em que não é possível substituir esse clítico 'reflexo' por um 'não reflexo' ou por um nome sem alterar o significado. Isto independentemente de o verbo pedir uma proposição em particular. *Passar-se* está nesta categoria; *passar* em *eu passo-me* não tem o mesmo significado que em *eu passo-te* ou em *eu passo a ponte*; mas *deitar* tem o mesmo sentido em *eu deito-me* e em *eu deito o bebé*.

Comment: @Jacinto Nem só de preposições são feitos verbos frasais. E sim, "eu me deitei com a Joana" tem um sentido completamente diferente de "eu me deitei". E "eu me deitei" tem sentido diferente de "eu deitei o bebê". "Deitar-se" é também o ato de ir dormir. Meramente "deitar o bebê" não implica que o mesmo vá dormir.

Answer (score 3):

Se o que queres é uma lista, podes ver o anexo da tese de doutoramento de Fernanda Rosário de Mello, intitulada [“Acabou-se o que era doce, quem comeu se regalou-se”: uma análise do clítico se em João Pessoa na interface Sociolinguística/Gramaticalização”](http://rei.biblioteca.ufpb.br/jspui/handle/123456789/339). No final, num anexo, há uma tabela de verbos com uma coluna *≠ SGDO*:

> A coluna [...] diz respeito a um critério semântico: a diferença de
>   significado quando o verbo se faz pronominalizado. Como indicam Cunha e Cintra
>   (1985), a instauração de um sentido distinto daquele dado pela forma não-pronominalizada é um forte indício de que estamos diante de um se que é inerente.

Answer (score 3):

Não encontrei nenhum nome para esse tipo de verbos. A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian tem trinta páginas de escrita cerrada e miudinha (1188-1218) sobre tipologia só dos verbos plenos, mas a classificação baseia-se apenas nos argumentos que o verbo seleciona — se tem ou não sujeito, complemento direto, etc. — e nas propriedades dos argumentos.

Mas não é difícil encontrar verbos com variação de significado associada ao pronome do paradigma reflexo. Encontrei dois tipos de variação: uma muito acentuada, em que os dois sentidos parecem não ter nada em comum; e verbos da chamada *alternância causativa-incoativa*, em que a diferença de significado é mais subtil. O que é comum a todos os casos é que o pronome ‘reflexo’ é na verdade inerente.

Comecemos com alguns exemplos das grandes diferenças. Algumas das aceções poderão ser desconhecidas no Brasil, por isso incluo uma curta explicação:

> **Dei** bem com o João (‘encontrei, descobri com facilidade’, [Priberam 28](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/dar))
> **Dei-me** bem com o João (‘relacionou-se, conviveu’, [Priberam 49, 50](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/dar))
>
> A Maria **passou** aqui com o namorado [(Priberam, 15, 19, 23)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/passar)
> A Maria **passou-se** aqui com o namorado (‘perdeu completamente a calma’, [Priberam 31](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/passar))
>
> **Vieram** os dois juntos
> **Vieram-se** os dois juntos (pois, coiso e tal, [Priberam 22](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/vir))

Estes exemplos têm a gracinha de o clítico ser a única diferença entre as frases. Se não formos tão exigente, encontramos mais exemplos:

> Ela **trata** da criança [(Priberam 6, 9)](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tratar)
> Temos de falar: **trata-se** da criança (‘o assunto é a criança’, [Priberam 20](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tratar))
>
> Ele **saiu** com uma moça engraçada (‘foi ao cinema’ ou coisa assim, [Priberam 17](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sair))
> Ele **saiu-se** com uma engraçada (‘disse inesperadamente’, [Priberam 20](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/sair))
>
> Esse circo **passou** em Coimbra [‘esteve’, [Priberam 23](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/passar))
> Esse circo **passou-se** em Coimbra [‘essa cena pouco edificante, etc. aconteceu’ [Priberam 29](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/passar))

Em todos estes exemplos, os verbos, tal como os verbos da tabela indicada na resposta do Artefacto, são usados intransitivamente; e o clítico é inerente. Ou seja o verbo não exprime uma ação que o sujeito exerça sobre si mesmo, como em *eu visto-me, ele veste-se*. Diferentemente o clítico faz parte do verbo, como em *arrepender-se*. (Isso confirma-se pela impossibilidade de acrescentar um *a mim mesmo, a si mesmo*, etc. ao verbo.) Note-se no entanto que clítico inerente não implica necessariamente que o mesmo verbo sem clítico tenha significado diferente. Por exemplo, *rir* e *rir-se* significam o mesmo.

Talvez não seja de surpreender que grandes diferenças de significado surjam com a adição do clítico apenas em verbos com clítico inerente. Se o clítico for verdadeiramente reflexo, em princípio o verbo admite complemento direto ‘normal’, mais ou menos com o mesmo significado. Na verdade é isso que acontece com *mudar*, o exemplo da pergunta. Imaginem que uma empresa tem residências próprias para empregados que vêm do estrangeiro:

> Entre colegas no departamento de alojamento: *Vamos **mudar o Silva** para a Av. De Roma*
>
> O Silva aos amigos: *Vou ter de **me mudar** para a Av. de Roma*

E se um verbo admite complemento direto, tipicamente será possível conjugá-lo reflexamente, mesmo quando seja materialmente impossível a sujeito exercer a ação sobre si mesmo:

> É materialmente impossível um líquido **beber-se** a si mesmo.
>
> Temos que **mudar o óleo** do carro, porque ele não **se muda** sozinho.

---

### Verbos da Alternância Causativa-Incoativa

Nestes verbos a diferença de significado é bem mais subtil. Vejamos um exemplo:

> (a) A Maria **assustou o João** = a Maria causou um susto ao João
> (b) A Maria **assustou-se** ≠ a Maria causou um susto a si mesma

Em (b) entendemos normalmente que alguma coisa ou alguém assustou a Maria. Se quiséssemos dizer que a Maria tinha, de algum modo, causado um susto a si mesma, teríamos que acrescentar um *a si mesma* para evitar a interpretação normal. Ou seja, *assustar* em (a) significa ‘causar um susto’; em (b) significa ‘sofrer um susto’. Em bom vernáculo diríamos (a) *pregar um susto* e (b) *apanhar um susto*, mas *causar* e *sofrer* são mais gerais e aplicam-se a qualquer verbo desta categoria. Estes verbos têm duas versões, como se vê melhor no seguinte exemplo:

> *Transitivo, causativo*: o estrondo **assustou a Maria**.
> *Intransitivo, incoativo*: a Maria **assustou-se** (com o estrondo).

Diz-nos a *Gramática do Português* (p. 1210) que «a grande maioria» do verbos da alternância causativa-incoativa têm pronome do paradigma reflexo na sua versão intransitiva. Nem todos têm: *o sol aqueceu a casa; a casa aqueceu*. Apresento os verbos com pronome ‘reflexo’ de entre a lista da *Gramática do Português*:

> *Verbos relativos a alterações psicológicas*: aborrecer (*ele aborreceu-me; eu aborreci-me*), afligir, assustar, comover, emocionar, enfurecer, envergonhar, escandalizar, espantar, inquietar, irritar, maçar, preocupar, ralar.
>
> *Verbos relativos a alterações físicas*: abrir (*o vento abriu a porta; a porta abriu-se*), afundar, agoniar, curar, encharcar, encher, fechar, girar, magoar, mover, queimar.